# position relative to fixed position div?

Tags: html, css, formatting, position, fixed

I want the main content to be displayed to the right of the left bar. Whether that's with fixed position or if there's some other way to do it. Doesn't really matter. Though, I don't want to use absolute positioning because I need my page to automatically format itself based on the size of the viewport. Also, the Left Bar isn't going to be a fixed width anyway. That'll be dependant on a number of things and may change multiple times during the same session. So absolute positioning is out of the question.

```
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="left_bar">Left Bar of Wonderfulness</div>
<div id="main_content">
    <p>I want this content to be displayed right around <b>here</b>. So it doesn't scroll behind "Left Bar of Wonderfulness".</p>

<p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>             <p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
</div>
```

```
#header{font-size:20vw;}
#left_bar{float:left;position:fixed;}
#main_content{overflow:auto;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QLADJ/

Y'know, I've asked a question here before, and got a similar response. Downvoted and answers completely irrelevant to my question. It's really NOT giving me a good impression of this place, I loathe having to ask any of you people anything. If you actually care about the site that you're trying to utilize, you should try to HELP the people on it, not attack them. -.-

Comment: Gotcha. Will edit my original post then.

Comment: If I knew that, I probably would not be asking for help here. It would be an easy fix in Javascript, but I'd prefer to just use CSS if at all possible.

Or, alternatively, have some other way to make a div not scroll with the page besides a fixed position.

Comment: you want the left menu to be visible even if the main content is scrolling down?

Comment: About your last paragraph: do realize it goes both ways. That paragraph it not giving "this place" a good impression of you either.

Comment: I don't particularly care if a bunch of people I dislike have a negative opinion of me though, is the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/VahST/) *Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, FF, Chrome, Safari

notice: although I'm using absolute positioning, this layout is completely responsive. (resize your browser to see it in action)

this solution still has a downside: the left menu width and the main content width are fixed. (I'll try to remedy that and update my answer)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Site">
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left_bar">Left Bar of Wonderfulness</div>
        <div id="main_content">
            <p>I want this content to be displayed right around <b>here</b>. So it doesn't scroll behind "Left Bar of Wonderfulness". Though, I don't want to use absolute positioning because I need my page to automatically format itself based on the size of the viewport. Also, the Left Bar isn't going to be a fixed width anyway. That'll be dependant on a number of things and may change multiple times during the same session. So absolute positioning is out of the question.</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

#Site
{
    height: 100%;
}
    #Site:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

#header
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10vw;
}
#content
{
    background-color: azure;
    position: relative;
}
    #content:after
    {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
#left_bar
{
    width: 30%;
}
#main_content
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Update:** your question was not so clear, but I think that I understood it correctly now.
Here is the [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/QCYRz/) *Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, Chrome, FF, Safari

the trick is to double the left menu content, one of them (the fake) - is hidden, but its there to take 'space', the real one is fixed.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Header">HEADER</div>
<div id="LeftMenuContainer">
    <div id="RealLeftMenu">Your left menu content</div>
    <div id="FakeLeftMenu">Your left menu content</div>
</div>
<div id="MainContent">
    Your content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#Header
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
}
#LeftMenuContainer
{
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#MainContent
{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}

#FakeLeftMenu
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#RealLeftMenu
{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

Comment: You've managed to restore a little faith in StackOverFlow to me, I genuinely appreciate you giving me an actual response relative to my question. I really do, thanks.

However; I do wish to make the header scroll with the page as well. I forgot to mention that though. And utilizing the page's scrollbar rather than a scrollbar on a div would be preferable.

Essentially, I only want the left bar to not scroll with the page, and everything else should.. Is there anyway to get THAT working? I'll settle for absolute positioning should it be unreasonable, but I really want to make it work.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I hadn't thought of that. Thanks a bunch!